# Selecting group of records with some NULL value in one of its fields

Tags: sql

Having a table such as this one:

```
season | month | coldest_temp
-----------------------------
winter | Dec   |  -5
winter | Jan   |  -8
winter | Feb   |  NULL
spring | Mar   |  7
spring | Apr   |  10
spring | May   |  15
```

How could I extract the group of seasons that has some NULL value in the field 'coldest_temp' (in this case the three winter records)? I imagine it must be using GROUP BY and HAVING, but I can't come up with a statement that would work :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Select season
From table group by season
having 1= sum(case when coldest_temp is null then 1 else 0 end) ;
```

Or for all columns try using correlated subquery

```
Select season, month
From table t where exists (
Select 1 from table where season=t.season and month < t.month and coldest_temp is null)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but I came across another problem.  Some of the fields may appear twice, for example winter-Feb-NULL might appear twice on the table because there's another field called time that has two distinct times.  Using

`having 1= sum(case when coldest_temp is null then 1 else 0 end) ;`

wouldn't work because the sum would be two.  Is there a way around that problem?

Comment: Try  1=< then itll work for all. Also, to avoid duplicates use distinct if that extra column is causing redundancy